# Question regarding eliminating volume term from Gauss Law

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, integration, calculus

*Gauss law* is given by

$$\oint_{\partial S}\vec E\cdot d\vec {A}=\dfrac{q_\text{enclosed}}{ε_0}.$$

$$q_\text{enclosed}=\iiint \rho\ dV.$$

For a closed surface $$\oint_{\partial S}\vec E\cdot d\vec{A}=\iiint (\nabla\cdot \vec{E})\ dV$$.

$$\implies \iiint (\nabla\cdot \vec{E})\ dV =\dfrac{\iiint \rho\ dV}{ε_0}.$$

What's the correct and intuitive way to remove the integral and $dV$ (volume element ) and give us the result (I don't know to establish a proper reasoning for eliminating the integral and $dV$).

$$\nabla\cdot E=\dfrac{ρ}{ε_0}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key realization is that the equality
$$
\int_\mathcal{V} \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} \, dV = \int_\mathcal{V} \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} \, dV
$$
must hold for *all volumes* $\mathcal{V}$.  By this, I mean that it is true when we integrate both the left-hand side and the right-hand side over *any* given region of space $\mathcal{V}$:  a sphere of radius 1 m around a point charge, my kitchen, a 50-light-year cube centered at Alpha Centauri, whatever.  We must also assume continuity of all functions involved.

Under these assumptions, we can prove the contrapositive of the given statement:

Suppose there exists some point $P$ in space where $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} - \rho/\epsilon_0 = c \neq 0$.  Suppose first that $c > 0$.  By continuity, this means that there is some small volume $\mathcal{V}$ surrounding $P$ such that $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} - \rho/\epsilon_0 > 0$ for all points within $\mathcal{V}$ (since by continuity, the value of $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} - \rho/\epsilon_0$ must be "close" to $c > 0$ for points sufficiently close to $P$.) This means that we must have
$$
\int \left( \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} - \rho/\epsilon_0 \right) \, dV > 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \int_\mathcal{V} \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} \, dV > \int_\mathcal{V} \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} \, dV$$
and so the integrals cannot be equal.  A similar argument follows if $c < 0$.

Therefore, the existence of a point $P$ at which $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} \neq \rho/\epsilon_0$ implies that a volume exists for which the integral form of Gauss's Law does not hold.  This therefore means that if Gauss's Law holds for all volumes, it must be the case that $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} = \rho/\epsilon_0$ at all points.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the term "for all volumes "

Comment: @HarryCase:  Edited to elaborate on what this means.

Comment: Are we coming to the conclusion that this integral  holds for every possible Volume ,so it has to be the case that the function over which we are integrating has to equal else this isn't possible ,this is the same case with every Maxwell law which can be written in  two forms ,a differential and an integral form

Comment: Yes, that's the conclusion we have reached;  and yes, similar arguments hold for the other three of Maxwell's equations.

Comment: Thank you so much .

Comment: .For Faraday's Law ,$$\oint E.dl=-\dfrac{d}{dt}\iint B.\hat{n}dA$$ ,now the LHS can be replaced by Stokes Theorem ,$\oint E.dl =\iint \nabla × E .\hat{n} dA$ .So the Faraday's Law becomes $\iint \nabla×E.\hat{n} dA = -\frac{d}{dt}\iint B.\hat {n}dA$ ,the one we discussed were scalar functions ,now do we remove a function under dot product ? Do we come to the conclusion that -$\dfrac{d}{dt} B.\hat{n} =\nabla×E .\hat{n}$ ? Then arrive at -$\dfrac{d}{dt}B=\nabla×E$,my question is just because projection of the two Vectors on $\hat{n}$ are equal ,why should the Vectors be equal.

Comment: @HarryCase:  By a similar argument, $\hat{n}$ can point in any possible direction, meaning that the projections of these two vectors along *any* unit vector are the same.  The only way for this to be true is if the two vectors are equal.

Comment: $\hat n$ is an arbitrary unit vector and if $\nabla ×E$ ,$-\dfrac{dB}{dt}$ have the same projection regardless of the direction of unit vector ,that means they have to be equal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138807/discussion-between-michael-seifert-and-harry-case).

Answer (score 0):

The integral equation
$$\iiint_V (\nabla\cdot \vec{E})\ dV =\frac{\iiint_V \rho\ dV}{ε_0}$$
is true for *every* volume $V$ independent of its shape.

This can only be true if the integrand functions
on the left and right side
are equal at every point in space:
$$\nabla\cdot \vec{E}=\dfrac{\rho}{ε_0}$$

Comment: But how can we be sure that the volume we are talking about on the left is the same as the volume on the right ?

Comment: @HarryCase:  They have to be the same volume for Gauss's Law to work.  Gauss's Law doesn't hold if you take the volume on the left-hand side to be my kitchen and the volume on the right-hand side to be a one-light-year sphere around Alpha Centauri.

Comment: Why not ? I know I am being stupid and missing something so obvious here ,but why can't there be a case where the divergence and $\dfrac{ρ}{ε_0}$ match the differences in Volume and make them equal

Comment: @HarryCase:  In your argument, you started with the flux through the surface $S$ enclosing some volume $V$.  The enclosed charge inside that region is the integral of $\rho$ over that same volume $V$.  And Gauss's Law says that you can relate the flux through $S$ to the integral of the divergence of the field over the volume enclosed by $S$, i.e., $V$.  So the two integrals are over the same region of space.

Comment: Yeah sorry totally forgot about that ,we are in effect considering the same region .